# XSLT Compare Attribute to Values

Tags: xml, xslt

Hey I have a quick question for my homework

I have a list in my xml with genres for a movieshop like this:

.....

```
<genre ID="G3" name="Action"/>
<genre ID="G4" name="Romance"/>
<genre ID="G5" name="Sci-fi">
```

....and more

and a movie list which reffers to the genres like this:

```
<movie ID = "F6" titel ="Blood Work" year = "2002" length = "109">
        <!-- Genres --> 
                <genre ID ="G11" />
                <genre ID ="G7" />
```

.....

In the picture you can see what I got so far. Instead of the Genre IDs(G5 and G3) and so on i want the names of it. 
Thats what i tired so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movieshop">
<table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
   <!--Strukturierung der Tabelle -->
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Genre</th>
      <th>Length (in Minuten)</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
   <!--fill table with the elements movies -->
     <xsl:for-each select="//movieshop/movies/movie">
    <tr>
     <!-- ID of the movie  -->
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></td>
     <!-- titel of the movie  -->
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@titel"/></td>
      <!-- Description of the movie  -->
      <td><xsl:value-of select="details/@inhalt"/></td>
       <!-- Genre of the movie  -->
    <td> 
    <xsl:for-each select="genre/@ID">
                    <xsl:call-template name="resultGenres">
                        <xsl:with-param name="id" select="."/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    </td>
       <!-- Length -->
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@length"/></td>
       <!-- Year -->
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@year"/></td>  
    </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="resultGenres">
            <xsl:param name="id"/>
    <!--Just testing what id is -->
            <p>Genre: <xsl:value-of select = "$id" /></p>
            <xsl:for-each select="//movieshop/genres/genre[ID=$id]">
                <xsl:call-template name="resultGenre"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="resultGenre">
        <xsl:value-of select="//movieshop/genres/genre/@name"/>
        <br/>
</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the error must be somewhere here:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//movieshop/genres/genre[ID=$id]">
```

there is no resultset for that even tho G1 and so on exist in my list.
Im sorry if i misspelled something in the code. Tried changing all words to english.
Thanks in advance :D

[Preview of my Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kijR.png)

Comment: I am not sure what they teach you, but I think you should learn about [**keys**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key).

Comment: haha sorry thats how my teacher wants it . We are not supposed to use keys

Comment: I haven't read your code, but this jumps out: `<xsl:for-each select="//movieshop/genres/genre[ID=$id]">` will not select anything, because `ID` is an **attribute**. -- P.S. Get a better teacher.

Comment: yes but if i try [@ID=$id] it doesnt work either :(

Comment: Well, if you post a minimal, but complete example of the XML input, we might be able to reproduce your problem and identify it - see: [mcve].

Comment: In your `resultGenre` template, you just need to do `<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>` as you are already positioned on the relevant `genres/genre` element at that point. Although, having a named template here is rather excessive. You could just do `<xsl:value-of select="//movieshop/genres/genre[@ID=$id]/@name" />` in the `resultGenres` template. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBug

Comment: thank you sir ! you are my hero. finally it works <3